# web3.js and require.js - unexpected identifiyer issue

Tags: web3js, mix

I'm testing the web3 api, but it seems to be an error when I try `require('web3')`.

Require.js indicates that there is an error inside web3.js, but I have the latest release of web3. Maybe I have a wrong use of it. Can you help me ?

You can find bellow my code and the error:

[image: console]

Comment: Can you just try `var web3 = require('web3');`?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the given path to web3.js. you are using `src="../Desktop/Blockchain.....`

to resolve that put the script web3.js in the same folder that your page HTML 'page1.html" .